# what do you mean by select 1 from sysobjects..?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Ive seen this query used to check whether a table exists or not:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND name = 'test' ) 
    drop table test
GO
```

Can i get an explanation as to how this particular code works and the need for 1 and sysobject ?

Comment: Which part confuses you? intent? sysobjects? select 1?
Have you checked documentation?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @ImrePühvel Select 1 and sysobjects

Comment: Did you try running the `SELECT`? Did you try replacing `1` with `*`? Did you check the documentation for [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql)?

Comment: The 'select 1' is indication if exists object type 'U' (table) with the name ('test')

Comment: I suppose it's worth pointing out that sysobjects will be depricated, you should be using sys.objects instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of given snippet is to ensure database tabel does not exist after it's ran. It achieves this by checking if table exists from system metainfo and dropping the table if it was found.

`sysobjects` is a the system table which [according to documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596(v=sql.110).aspx):

> Contains one row for each object that is created within a database, such as a constraint, default, log, rule, and stored procedure.

According the doc linked above table named "test" is represented in that table by `type = 'U' AND name = 'test'`. Since we only care about the existence of a row and no actual value is needed then we are selecting any small contant value, hence `select 1`. It could also have been `select 'yabadabadoo'`if you liked it more.

Also, note documentation emphasizes that given table `sysobjects` is deprecated and should not be used anymore and hints that you should use view `sys.objects` instead.

Comment: On top of the nice explanation, 'select 1' means 'select the first column', in case there is confusion to new user.

Comment: Well, no. In MS Sql Server & TSQL, `select 1` means "select a literal number 1 for each found row".

Answer (score 0):

If the particular table is available in the database this script drops the same. Select '1' indicates the existence of table. sysobjects contains list of objects available in the database. Type='U' defines the object type as user table.This script is mostly used before altering any object.